# "ValueError: Unsupported format character ' " ' (0x22) at..." in Python / String

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I've seen a couple similar threads, but attempting to escape characters isn't working for me.

In short, I have a list of strings, which I am iterating through, such that I am aiming to build a query that incorporates however many strings are in the list, into a 'Select, Like' query.

Here is my code (Python)

```
def myfunc(self, cursor, var_list):
   query = "Select var FROM tble_tble WHERE"
   substring = []
   length = len(var_list)
   iter = length

   for var in var_list:
      if (iter != length):
         substring.append(" OR tble_tble.var LIKE %'%s'%" % var)
      else:
         substring.append(" tble_tble.var LIKE %'%s'%" % var)
      iter = iter - 1

   for str in substring:
      query = query + str
...
```

That should be enough. If it wasn't obvious from my previously stated claims, I am trying to ***build a query which runs the SQL 'LIKE'*** comparison across a *list* of relevant strings.

Thanks for your time, and feel free to ask any questions for clarification.

Comment: `%` should be inside the quotes when you use `LIKE`.

Comment: and... does it make any sense that you write both: iter = length and if (iter != length):?

Comment: It was the first thing that came to mind to make sure I didn't include OR on the first iteration. I probably could've used a flag but this code isn't optimized at all yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, your problem has nothing to do with SQL. Throw away all the SQL-related code and do this:

```
var = 'foo'
" OR tble_tble.var LIKE %'%s'%" % var
```

You'll get the same error. It's because you're trying to do `%`-formatting with a string that has stray `%` signs in it. So, it's trying to figure out what to do with `%'`, and failing.

---

You can escape these stray `%` signs like this:

```
" OR tble_tble.var LIKE %%'%s'%%" % var
```

However, that probably isn't what you want to do.

---

First, consider using `{}`-formatting instead of `%`-formatting, *especially* when you're trying to build formatted strings with `%` characters all over them. It avoids the need for escaping them. So:

```
" OR tble_tble.var LIKE %'{}'%".format(var)
```

---

But, more importantly, you shouldn't be doing this formatting at all. Don't format the values into a SQL string, just pass them as SQL parameters. If you're using sqlite3, use `?` parameters markers; for MySQL, `%s`; for a different database, read its docs. So:

```
" OR tble_tble.var LIKE %'?'%"
```

There's nothing that can go wrong here, and nothing that needs to be escaped. When you call `execute` with the query string, pass `[var]` as the args.

This is a lot simpler, and often faster, and neatly avoids a lot of silly bugs dealing with edge cases, and, most important of all, it protects against SQL injection attacks.

The [sqlite3 docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html) explain this in more detail:

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations… Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method. (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as %s or :1.) …

---

Finally, as others have pointed out in comments, with `LIKE` conditions, you have to put the percent signs *inside* the quotes, not *outside*. So, no matter which way you solve this, you're going to have another problem to solve. But that one should be a lot easier. (And if not, you can always come back and ask another question.)

Comment: I don't know Python well, but I'll bet `%%` in a format string expands to a `%`.

Comment: @Barmar: Which is exactly what (I assume) the OP wants.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you. My knowledge of format strings is very ... amateur.

Comment: @abarnert What do you mean by passing them as SQL parameters? You seem to know your stuff.

Comment: @jdero: This is explained near the very top of [the `sqlite3` docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html) (and the DB-API 2.0 PEP, and similar places). See the two paragraphs and example starting with "Usually your SQL operations…"

Comment: @jdero: Also see [this XKCD strip](http://xkcd.com/327/) for an explanation of why you might want to use SQL parameter binding (or input sanitization, but parameter binding is a whole lot simpler and safer).

Comment: I actually remember that from my dbm class :D just never put it into practice until this awful moment! Thanks for your help. Great links, and solid extension in your post.

Comment: @abarnert I know comments are not chat threads, but I just found it utterly hilarious, the intern next to me was like "Hey, I think I have an xkcd on my back, what does it say?" And it was *that exact* xkcd article. Coincidence? I think not :)

Comment: @jdero: Sometimes you can learn more from interns' t-shirts than you can from StackOverflow or documentation. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `%` like this you need to change the quotes to include the both `%` generate proper SQL

```
" OR tble_tble.var LIKE '%%%s%%'"
```

For example:

```
var = "abc"
print " OR tble_tble.var LIKE '%%%s%%'" % var
```

It will be translated to:

```
OR tble_tble.var LIKE '%abc%'
```

Comment: In standard SQL, and with most actual databases, the LIKE condition's pattern expression has to be a string value in quotes (or a bound parameter, of course).

Comment: @abarnert Thank you. Updated. I am a bit slow today and was not processing somehow...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so here is what I had to do to make this work with recent releases of all software mentioned above:

```
citp = "SomeText" + "%%"  # if your LIKE wants database rows that match start text, else ... 
citp = "%%" + "SomeQueryText" + "%%"   

        chek_copies = 'SELECT id, code, null as num from indicator WHERE code LIKE "%s" AND owner = 1 ;'
        check_copies = (chek_copies % (citp))
        copies_checked = pd.read_sql(check_copies, con=engine)
```

Works like a charm - but what a  load of trial and error